# jungledisk fails with libnotify error

Tags: jungledisk, online-storage

Has anyone had success getting the jungledisk application to work under Ubuntu?

I installed it from the .deb file provided by jungledisk. The install goes fine, but I can't get the "jungle disk desktop" app to launch.

It appears in the dash search bar, but doesn't launch or do anything upon selecting it.

When I try the command line, I get the following...

```
$ jungledisk -V -f
Verbose mode enabled
Shutting down...
$
```

I get something more interesting with the following command ... something about libnotify.so

```
$ junglediskdesktop -V -f
junglediskdesktop: error while loading shared libraries: libnotify.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Does anyone have suggestions for what to try?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The helpticket folks at jungledisk/rackspace resolved this problem. It appears that jungledisk was expecing libnotify.so.1 and ubuntu had libnotify.so.4.

Creating a symlink pointing to libnotify.so.4 resolves the problem...

> The new Ubuntu is missing libnotify.so.1 needed by jungle disk. This
>   is resolved by creating a symlink to libnotify.so.4 to libnotify.so.1.
>   Please [enter the commands] below and restart the machine:
>
> **`cd /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/ ; sudo ln -s ./libnotify.so.4 libnotify.so.1`**
>
> Regards, JungleJason

Comment: FYI... I had the same problem in an install of 32bit xubuntu. The above fixed it also.

Comment: 64-bit users check Kailash's solution instead.

Comment: The symlink fix works on 12.10 as well.

Answer (score 15):

For a 64-bit version of Ubuntu, the other answer won't work, because the relevant library paths are different.  However, the [solution from the linuxmint forums](http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=47&t=87662&p=510737) does work:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnotify.so.4 /usr/lib/libnotify.so.1
```

Comment: Thanks! They're actually very similar. The idea is to create a symbolic link so that libnotify.so.1 points to the libnotify.so.4. There are differences because you're apparently using 64 bit and I am using 32 bit. I had originally indicated 32bit in my title, but it was edited out.

Comment: I can confirm that I indeed use 64 bit.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. End up using the free Linux tools from SMEStorage:

http://smestorage.com/?p=static&page=LinuxDrive

Comment: Thanks, I will consider using that. But before I do, I have a bunch of data on s3 via jungledisk to migrate!

Answer (score 0):

Rackspace has posted an official set of instructions over at:
https://support.jungledisk.com/entries/21726460
For both 32 and 64 bit versions. Note as of this writing the solution does not work properly for Ubuntu 13.04.