# Ubuntu 11.10 issues with jungledisk desktop

Tags: 11.10, upgrade, jungledisk

Since I've upgraded to 11.10, I cannot get my jungledisk application to work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jungledisk 3.16 doesn't launch](http://askubuntu.com/questions/84182/jungledisk-3-16-doesnt-launch)

Answer (score 2):

If you are running a 64-bit install, run the following command post install of jungledisk.

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnotify.so.4 /usr/lib/libnotify.so.1
```

Answer (score 1):

`jungledisk` is available from the [Jungle Disk downloads page](https://www.jungledisk.com/downloads/personal/desktop/linux/).

Open a terminal and download `jungledisk`

*32bit Ubuntu*

```
cd ~ && wget https://downloads.jungledisk.com/jungledisk/junglediskdesktop_316-0_i386.deb
```

*64bit Ubuntu*

```
cd ~ && wget https://downloads.jungledisk.com/jungledisk/junglediskdesktop_316-0_amd64.deb
```

(Re) install it and remove the installer

```
sudo dpkg -i ~/junglediskdesktop*.deb && rm ~/junglediskdesktop*.deb
```

You need to create this a symlink link to `libnotify.so.4` with the name `libnotify.so.1` inside `/usr/lib.i386-linux-gnu/`, to it with this command

```
cd /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/ ; sudo ln -s ./libnotify.so.4 libnotify.so.1
```

After this `jungledisk` is installed you can launch it from the terminal with `junglediskdesktop` or by looking for it on the dash.

Answer (score 0):

Rackspace has posted an extensive post on this matter with a solution (but not yet a promise to recompile their client software):

https://support.jungledisk.com/entries/21726460