# Jungle Disk Desktop stopped working in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: jungledisk

I've recently upgraded from to Ubuntu 12.04.  When I upgraded, I re-installed Jungle Disk Desktop and it was working fine, but a couple of days later, I started getting a jungle disk error saying to check the application for details.  That's when I discovered that I couldn't get to the application.  I tried whitelisting the application, but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Did you check that libnotify.so.1 is symlinked to libnotify.so.4? ( http://askubuntu.com/questions/84182/jungledisk-3-16-doesnt-launch )

Comment: Thanks for responding, Angelo!  When I did the symlink in terminal, I got a message saying libnotify.so.4 already existed.  What's next?

Comment: Try launching from the commandline in verbose mode and see what it says: junglediskdesktop -V -f

Comment: I'll try this when I get home and let you know what happens.

Answer (score 2):

[This blog](http://fleabittenvarmint.us/tech/jungledisk_ubuntu12.php) talks about how they solved the same problem

In short, you need to enter this into a terminal to create a symlink:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnotify.so.4 /usr/lib/libnotify.so.1
```

Comment: Quoting OP comment in her question: "Thanks for responding, Angelo! When I did the symlink in terminal, I got a message saying libnotify.so.4 already existed".