# Getting Jungledisk working on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, unity, system-tray, jungledisk

I'm trying to get the desktop client for Jungledisk working on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, so that I can restore some family photos which have been backed-up into a jungledisk-format backup vault (which can't be done through their web interface or using the command-line `jungledisk` command).

I've successfully installed Jungle Disk (from 64-bit deb) and sorted out the LibNotify error as discussed here:
[jungledisk fails with libnotify error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/84182/jungledisk-fails-with-libnotify-error).

Then the first time I started junglediskdesktop it ran ok (i.e. windows appeared and so on), and I set up the config.

So now it seems to be configured correctly, but when I run it:

- The first time it seems to do nothing at all,
- The second time it gives this error "Jungle Disk Desktop is running in standalone mode and has detected that the service is already running, or the service network port is in use. Please stop the service, or run Jungle Disk Desktop in non-standalone mode."

So I've googled for solutions and tried the recommendation from here:
[How to solve Jungledisk’s "Background Service Error” under Ubuntu 11.04 Unity](https://aceontech.wordpress.com/2011/08/07/how-to-solve-jungledisks-background-service-error-under-ubuntu-11-04-unity/)
to install `dconf-editor` and "append the string ‘junglediskdesktop’ to the systray-whitelist enumeration" - but I can't do that because (it turns out) that doesn't apply in this version of Ubuntu. (I.e. it seems that JungleDisk is trying but failing to appear in the systray, and I don't have any other way of getting it to open up a proper window so I can use it).

So I've tried the recommendation here:
[How to whitelist systray apps in Ubuntu 14.04 or 14.10 (w/ Unity)](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/05/how-to-get-systray-whitelist-back-in.html)
for whitelisting systray apps in Ubuntu 14.04 - I've done

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gurqn/systray-trusty
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

but Jungle Disk is not showing up anywhere - it seems to have made no difference.

I've also looked at the advice here:
[Getting Desktop or Workgroup Edition working on Ubuntu (12.04 and 13.04)](https://support.jungledisk.com/hc/en-us/articles/200812754-Getting-Desktop-or-Workgroup-Edition-working-on-Ubuntu-13-04-and-12-04-)

but that seems not to apply to Ubuntu 14 either (the panel entry it refers to is not present in `dconf-editor`).

If anyone knows how I can get it working and usable enough to restore the files from the archive, then I'd be grateful.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this same problem in Ubuntu 15.04 64-bit using the instructions for installing the "Indicator Systemtray Unity" as described in the answer to this question here: 
[How to re-enable the systray (indicator panel) after latest updates](https://askubuntu.com/questions/612912/how-to-re-enable-the-systray-indicator-panel-after-latest-updates)
After following the installation instructions, including logging out and logging back in, the new applet was present. Clicking on the applet revealed my previously-hidden system tray icons, including jungledisk. Clicking on that jungledisk icon brought me to the jungledisk window, where I could do backups and restores.